# Encoding URL partially in Javascript and PHP (url tweak)

Tags: php, javascript, regex, apache, urlencode

that might be something strange when I say that I want to encode a URL partially, But I am caught in this situation and it seems that I got no other solution...

here is my code snippet

```
    $url = isset($_GET['u']) ? esc_url($_GET['u']) : '';
        $image = isset($_GET['i']) ? $_GET['i'] : '';


   maybeappend = '<a href="?ajax=photo_thickbox&amp;i=' + encodeURIComponent(img.src) +
   '&amp;u=<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>&amp;height=400&amp;width=500" title="" 
    class="thickbox"><img src="' + img.src + '" ' + img_attr + '/></a>';
```

its taken from wordpress `/wp-admin/press-this.php`
the issue is, I cant post to my site via `Press this` bookmarklet

I searched the google, studied the wordpress forums and found that I need to tweek `Press this` button in my bookmark tool bar in broswer..

but for me, that is not a solution,,why? obviously, I cant teach every visitor to do this change in their broswer..so I have to edit my code residing on server...

how can I edit `encodeURIComponent(img.src)` and `<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>` so it DOES NOT ENCODE `HTTP://` part of url,

say I got a url 'http://www.google.com I want it to be encoded as `www.google.com`

any suggesion?

How can I achieve my goal? might be some regex ? (dont know regex :(  )

what would be the code adjustment for this??

thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

First remove the http part using substr, then apply urlencode and then reattacht the http part.

Same method can be applied in JavaScript using the equivalent JavaScript functions.

```
$encoded = 'http://' . urlencode(substr($url, -7));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed use a regex to filter the `http://` part of the url (which is, if I understood well, what you want to do).

Something like `https?://(.*)` should select the part of the url you want (the `s?` part takes into account potential secure links).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure any matching strings are at the beginning of the strings

**Javascript**
Use String.replace with regex:

```
url.replace( /^(http|https):\/\//, '' );
```

`^` means start of the string

**PHP**
Use str_replace(): [php.net/str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
if( strpos( $url, 'http' ) == 0 ){
    str_replace( array( 'http://', 'https://'), '', $url, 1 );
}
```

`strpos` can also return a `FALSE` so make sure you use `==`.

Comment: thanks, but I am not sure, how can I edit the code given above